# Always mention that something is an add-on when referencing add-on features

Tags: discussion

I recently had an experience trying to answer a user's question that was very confusing because that user neglected to mention that the feature he was referring to is only available after enabling a certain add-on.

Maybe this isn't such a big deal that it deserves a post, but then again I think it's common sense and we should somehow get the message out to users that just because *they* may think everyone knows about their add-ons doesn't necessarily mean it is so.

Having the courtesy to type "add-on" somewhere in the question isn't an unreasonable request.

Thoughts and ideas, anyone?

Comment: We have an [tag:add-on] tag, IMO any question using an addon should use this tag.  But AFAIK there really isn't any way to force people to use it.

Comment: @PGmath I would *not* encourage tag usage like that. The tags should be describing what the question is about. You should defanitly put in your question that such and such is done by addon X, but to tag every question that has a problem where the user has used an addon is too broad.

Comment: @David What I mean is that, iff the addon is a necessary element of the problem (which I think is what mentalist means) it should be tagged addon.

Comment: Yes, and yes. If knowledge of the add-on is *required* to answer the question, users should use the add-on tag. However, tagging *all* questions that mention add-ons would be overkill and not helpful. As for a place where such community guidelines can be posted, I don't know that SE currently offers such an area(?) I'm imagining something like reddit's sidebar and I can't think of an equivalent on Stack Exchange.